# Read in class names from stylesheet

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've been following along with a React starter kit, and stumbled upon [the following](https://github.com/przeor/ReactC/blob/develop/src/routes/Home/components/HomeView.js):

```
import React from 'react'
import DuckImage from '../assets/Duck.jpg'
import classes from './HomeView.scss'

export const HomeView = () => (
  <div>
    <h4>Welcome!</h4>
    <img
      alt='This is a duck, because Redux!'
      className={classes.duck}
      src={DuckImage} />
  </div>
)
```

There is a `duck` class in the SCSS file, and somehow that's getting read in and assigned as a property of the `classes` object. Cool! Anyone know how that's being done? I went through the [package.json](https://github.com/przeor/ReactC/blob/develop/package.json) and couldn't figure out the library/tool that was making this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straight forward.

All the classes in your `SCSS` will be converted into style objects. Each class will a `property` in that style object. This `property` will carry the information about `className` and the `style`.

So when you do

```
import classes from './HomeView.scss'
```

the `css-loader` and the `sass-loader` will read the `HomeView.scss` file and convert them into style object. Once this is done, the style object will be `exported` which is consumed and assigned to `classes`.

Now, when you do

```
classes.duck
```

the class name of the property `duck` will be returned.

If you try `console.log(classes)`, you'll see all the classes from the scss file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader

This is the sass loader to load classes

```
"sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
```